# Simple data load in Python-Guroby

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple LP problem in Python-Guroby. I have some data which I want to use. The problem is I am not sure how to `addVar` in my model using a for loop for my data which I have put them in a list. Let's say for example I have `Costs = [1054.3, 1600.3, 1750.45]`.

```
from gurobipy import *    
m = Model()
```

What I am trying is this but I have no idea if it is correct:

```
 x = []
 for cost in Costs:
     x.append([m.addVar(obj=cost)])
```

Anyone has any clue how can I do it?

Comment: Please put your code in a code block and indent it correctly.

Comment: What's not working? What type of problem are you experiencing?
Also: Append takes an element that you want to append to your list. Do you want to have x as a list of lists?

Comment: I corrected that, now i have x as a list and not list of lists. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: So is it working now? ^^

Comment: Yes, it is working. Just used two loops on top and it seems okay. Thanks very much